# IE finding JS variable from newWindow.var

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have two files that each has JS, and I have one file that opens a new window and passes that new window

```
newWindow.arrayArr = foo;
```

The other file then tries to access via:

```
arrayArr.each(do something)
```

This works great in everything but IE (surprise) I know that in IE it is not finding the var and says it is undefined. Is there any way for IE to find the variable without changing the structure of the files?

Comment: Have you tried another name, such as `axxay` instead of `array` ?

Comment: @JonSnow I have tried it on IE 8, 9, and 10

Comment: @EugenRieck sorry for the confusion, I actually have another name for it. I just used array as an example, I'll change it to what it really is!

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an error because of `.each`? The correct loop is `.forEach` and that isn't supported in IE8. Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @JonSnow Yeah I tried using a for each but it still gives me an undefined name problem

Comment: Then some browser security feature might be blocking you, as an alternative you can try and set the variable in `localStorage` and retrieve it from there.

Comment: @JonSnow The local storage works for me, except I have an object that I am trying to send using localStorage so I tried to use JSON.stringify() but that doesn't seem to be working? Any reasons why this would not work?

Comment: Hmm it should work(I've done it before and it worked fine). Are you sure that in the other window you're doing `JSON.parse` in order to turn it back into an object? So in the end you do JSON.stringify -> set in localStorage -> JSON.parse in other window

Comment: For some reason when I debug it says stringify is not a method, so I ended having to use JSON.encode()/ JSON.decode() and that seemed to work fine!